# android publish app with google maps api

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-widget

hello I build application with google maps api , 
the apk work fine till i export sign apk (for publish on google play)
when i download the application from google play

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=beach.android.com&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsImJlYWNoLmFuZHJvaWQuY29tIl0.

i can't see the map.

the export sign apk destroy the map

anyone know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the map api, you are using an api key. The api key is bound to a specific certificate, and right now it is bound to your debug certificate. You just need to get an api key for your production certificate.

See here: https://developers.google.com/android/maps-api-signup

EDIT: This is no longer relevant with Maps API v2